# Ubuntu google authenticator only for ssh not physical machine

Tags: ssh, two-factor-authentication

I set up google authenticator for ssh login, and it works fine.

However, when restart the computer and login form the physical machine, it requires the google autheticator code also - is it possible to change it so this is ONLY for ssh?

Comment: How did you set this up in the first place?  Did you use a specific guide?  (The DigitalOcean guide I found *only* configures 2FA for SSH connections and not system-wide...)